# Bouncy Castle issue and Triple DES

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, tripledes

Hi I have a client using Triple DES.  I know I know if AES I would not have a problem it is a older solution integration.  I have code below that Takes in a file and writes to another.  On the decrypt method I don't understand the 2nd parameter for length of the file.  Please help.  The error I get is the following: 
**Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: last block incomplete in decryption
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at DESede_BC.decrypt(DESede_BC.java:102)
    at DESede_BC.main(DESede_BC.java:120)**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;



import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.ShortBufferException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.DESedeEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;

public class DESede_BC {

PaddedBufferedBlockCipher encryptCipher;
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher decryptCipher;

// Buffers used to transport the bytes from one stream to another
byte[] buf = new byte[8];       //input buffer - block size length
byte[] obuf = new byte[557];    //output buffer

byte[] key = null;              //the key

public DESede_BC(){
    //use a default 192 bit key
    key = "thekey".getBytes();
    InitCiphers();
}
public DESede_BC(byte[] keyBytes){
    key = new byte[keyBytes.length];
    System.arraycopy(keyBytes, 0 , key, 0, keyBytes.length);
    InitCiphers();
}

private void InitCiphers(){
    encryptCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new DESedeEngine());
    encryptCipher.init(true, new KeyParameter(key));
    decryptCipher =  new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new DESedeEngine());
    decryptCipher.init(false, new KeyParameter(key));
}

public void ResetCiphers() {
    if(encryptCipher!=null)
        encryptCipher.reset();
    if(decryptCipher!=null)
        decryptCipher.reset();
}

public void encrypt(InputStream in, long length, OutputStream out)
throws ShortBufferException, 
    IllegalBlockSizeException,
    BadPaddingException,
    DataLengthException,
    IllegalStateException,
    InvalidCipherTextException
{
    try {
    // Bytes written to out will be encrypted
    // Read in the cleartext bytes from in InputStream and
    //      write them encrypted to out OutputStream

    int noBytesRead = 0;        //number of bytes read from input
    int noBytesProcessed = 0;   //number of bytes processed

    while ((noBytesRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        noBytesProcessed =
                encryptCipher.processBytes(buf, 0, noBytesRead, obuf, 0);
        out.write(obuf, 0, noBytesProcessed);
    }
     noBytesProcessed =
             encryptCipher.doFinal(obuf, 0);

     out.write(obuf, 0, noBytesProcessed);

    out.flush();
}
catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
}
    public void decrypt(InputStream in,long length, OutputStream out)
   throws ShortBufferException, IllegalBlockSizeException,  BadPaddingException,
        DataLengthException, IllegalStateException, InvalidCipherTextException
    {
        try {
        // Bytes read from in will be decrypted
        // Read in the decrypted bytes from in InputStream and and
        //      write them in cleartext to out OutputStream

        int noBytesRead = 0;        //number of bytes read from input
        int noBytesProcessed = 0;   //number of bytes processed

        while ((noBytesRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
                noBytesProcessed = decryptCipher.processBytes(buf, 0, noBytesRead, obuf, 0);
                out.write(obuf, 0, noBytesProcessed);
        }
        noBytesProcessed = decryptCipher.doFinal(obuf, 0);
        out.write(obuf, 0, noBytesProcessed);

        out.flush();
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String... args)
        throws Exception
      {

    DESede_BC d = new DESede_BC();
FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("c:\\2.in");
FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream("c:\\decrypted.txt");

    d.decrypt(fis2, new Long("128"), fos2);



      }

}
```

Comment: The length argument seems to make sense in this context only as the length of the cipher file, which you can get from e.g. `new File("c:\\2.in").length()`

Comment: I cannot help wondering if there is an end of file marker or something being read and making it into the decrypt routine.  If there is, it would not look like the expected padding, and it would not fill the block, so this would certainly cause the exception you are seeing.  Unfortunately I have not worked with Java in some time and have no IDE for it on this computer, so I cannot test my theory.  But try examining in a debugger the final block being passed to the decryptor.  If it is an end of file marker, manually remove it from the decrypt stream.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing on my end.  Turns out that the base64 fixed it.  ugh...  AES?  I mean little behind in the client sense.  Thanks for your feedback!  Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to decode your input into Base64 before doFinal:

```
byte[] obuf = Base64.decode(obuf, Base64.NO_OPTIONS);
byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(obuf);
```

Comment: Your suggestion was exactly what I needed to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I used DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(line);  Your Rock!

Comment: @ogottwald ...great. Glad I could help.